# no Permission to read my own Firestore collection (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm receiving this error when I try to read one of my Firestore collections:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

This is my Firestore Inicialization:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And this is my try to access my collections:

```
Future initFirestore() async {
  var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  //firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
  QuerySnapshot resultado = await firestore.collection("users").get();
  print(resultado);
}
```

(I see some people talking about something that fix this, but Stackoverflow don't let me ask how to get in the document that those people were)

Please send help. You, stackoverflow, is the last hope

Comment: What are your rules set up as? Got to console.firebase.google.com => Cloud Firestore => Rules

Comment: OHHH! is this page that those people were talking about. My rules is: allow read, write:  if false. But It look s like if you turn it to "True" anyone can write and read, I think. Anyways, thanks. Now I can continue my work

Answer (score 2):

Allowing your users to read and write to your DB can be manipulated by updating the rules to your Cloud Firestore. (Found in console.firebase.google.com => Cloud Firestore => Rules)

If you would like to have all access (Nice to use while testing, but probably should be updated when you go live)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: true;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want only auth'd users to access your DB you can add the following

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the docs for the [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) that you can brush up on to finetune your rules.